# Receiving segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c

I have this code, but with certain input file, I keep getting segmentation fault:11. Xcode is showing an error after running in this line:

```
st[i] = ch;
```

All of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10000


void string_reverse(char st[]);

int main (int argc, char** argv) {


    char line[MAX];
    char reverse[MAX]="",temp[MAX];
    int i,j;
    /*
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        printf("per mazai argumentu \n");
        return 0;
    }*/

    FILE *in  = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    while(fgets(line, 255, in))
    {

        size_t n = strlen(line);

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for(j = 0; i < n && line[i]!=' '; ++i,++j) {

                temp[j] = line[i];

            }

            temp[j] = '\0';

            string_reverse(temp);

            strcat(reverse, temp);
            strcat(reverse, " ");
        }
    }
    fprintf(out, "%s\n",reverse);

    return 0;
}


/*apversti */
void string_reverse(char st[]) {
    int i;
    char ch;

    size_t j  = strlen(st)-1 ;
    i = 0;

    if(st[j]=='\n')
    {
        st[j]='\n';
        j--;
    }
    while(i < j) {
        ch = st[j];
        st[j] = st[i];
        st[i] = ch;
        i++;
        j--;

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish with `if (st[j] == '\n') { st[j] = '\n'; j--; }` - do you mean `if (st[j] == '\n' { st[j--] = '\0'; }` ?

Comment: Use the debugger to investigate more. For example, what are the values of `i` and `j` when the seg fault occurs? Are the values valid? If not, back track and step thru the code to see how those values occured.

Comment: @SteveFriedl The program was moving endline to front of a string, so this fixed it, by not moving it.

Comment: @kaylum just done that. i=98 and j =18446744073709551517. Probably there's the problem, but why does it do that?

Comment: Continue to use your debugger. Put in breakpoints and step thru the code. It will be of great long term benefit to you to learn to debug effectively on your own.

Comment: What is `strlen(st)` the second time you enter `string_reverse` ? If it's zero, then j will be a very very large number.

Comment: You might also want to trace the value of `i` in main to see if it really keeps increasing as you expect it should, or if it "gets stuck" after a certain point.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That helped me, the problem was that a line started with '  ' and so strlen(st) overflowed causing problems.

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconverson -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the saje results.

Comment: note: the function: `strlen()` returns the OFFSET (which starts at 0) to the trailing NUL byte.  So (I think) this statement: `size_t j  = strlen(st)-1 ;` is not correct.  Suggest: `size_t j  = strlen(st) ;` so the last valid character in the line is not skipped

Comment: regarding: `if(st[j]=='\n')
    {
        st[j]='\n';`  This code has absolutely no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <string.h>

void string_reverse(char st[]) 
{
    for( size_t i = 0, j = strlen( st ); i<j; i++, j-- )
    {
        char temp = st[i];
        st[i] = st[j];
        st[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: the NUL is part of the string.  If the OP did not want to  copy that character, they should have said so.  to not copy the NUL, use: `size_t j = strlen(st); if( j >0 ) {j--;} for( size_t i = 0; i<j; i++, j-- )`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that `size_t j  = strlen(st)-1 ;` was overflowing when my text line started with ' '.